# How did the Senate filibuster rules apply to Sen Rand Paul's filibuster?

Tags: united-states, congress, senate-rules, filibuster

I understand the basics of a Senate Filibuster. But after Sen Rand Paul's filibuster on 3/6/2013 he was interviewed by CNN and mentioned:

> The floor was left unguarded.

Was he referring to a specific Senate Rule that allows a filibuster to start? If not what was he referring to as "unguarded"?

[Youtube link to interview](http://youtu.be/nwvj-a_iDRQ?t=8m44s)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a senator is speaking on the Senate floor, no other senator may begin speaking unless the speaker [yields the floor](http://www.rules.senate.gov/public/index.cfm?p=RuleXIX). Sen. Paul meant that no one could stop him from beginning his filibuster because no one was speaking at the time.

Comment: Didn't realize it was that simple. How is the floor typically guarded?